# Jquery блокировка событий, вызываемых вложенными элементами

Tags: jquery, события

Есть слой, в нем располагаются различные элементы - кнопки, ссылки, раскрывающиеся меню и.д. Как блокировать все события этих элементов через слой?

```
    $('.item-content a, .item-content input, .item-content button, .item-content image').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Сейчас используется вот такая "заглушка", а как сделать что-то вроде:

```
$('.item-content').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может?

```
$('.item-content *').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

});

Comment: вообще гадание не есть гуд, но вариант подошел, спасибо